# Spark-streaming with Hbase : Cannot establish connection with Hbase

Tags: java, hbase, spark-streaming

I am writing a Java Kafka Spark Streaming program which ultimately has to write in the Hbase table. But it is failing in establishing the connection with Hbase. Can anyone tell me what i have to do?

```
        Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "127.0.0.1");
        config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
        config.set("hbase.master", "127.0.0.1:60000");

        HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(config);
        System.out.println("HBase is running!");

        Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);

        table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName));
```

ERROR:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
```

Maven dependencies :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-testing-util</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The zookeeper was down. Getting it back up solved the issue for me.